# livepatch not livepatching very much

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I have been running canonical-livepatch for a year or so but constantly find that I have to reboot my server due to kernel patching. Now recently I have been running Linux kernel 5.11.0-1021-aws.

Then recently came a security patch https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5135-1 which was installed (automatically). Now the system requires me to reboot because of this tiny patch.

```
$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs

linux-image-5.11.0-1022-aws
linux-base
```

---

```
canonical-livepatch status

last check: 35 minutes ago
kernel: 5.11.0-1021.22~20.04.2-aws
server check-in: succeeded
patch state: ✓ no livepatches needed for this kernel yet
tier: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)
machine id: ec22769b485772537a25ff41239f34b3
```

Is this how livepatch is supposed to work? I find myself rebooting the system at least once per month due to kernel patches. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe my system installs the patch before live-patch have a chance? Or have I simply misunderstood how live patch is working?

All the best !
Daniel

Comment: I tried it out for a long time after it first came out. AFAIK I never got a patch. My conclusion: unneeded overhead. So I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

After further reading I concluded that canonical-livepatch only patches the most critical updates in summary very few per year.